# Ending a line of code in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How do a do something like this using HAML:

`<%= Student.name %> and <%= Student.age %> are required.`

Or in my specific situation:

```
%tbody
  - @quotes.each do |quote|
    %tr
      %td= time_ago_in_words quote.created_at ago
```

If you look closely, I'm just trying to output "2 months ago" instead of just "2 months"

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "end a line of code" in HAML, but you can combine code and plain text in any number of ways:

1. String interpolation:

   ```haml
   %td #{time_ago_in_words quote.created_at} ago
   ```
2. Concatenation:

   ```haml
   %td= time_ago_in_words(quote.created_at) + " ago"
   ```
3. Separation of text/code lines:

   ```haml
   %td
     = time_ago_in_words quote.created_at
     ago
   ```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for showing all the different ways to do it! The third option is what I was looking for! Thanks again!